# How to change color of pixel on screen with python 3.9

Tags: python, user-interface, colors, screen

How could I make something simple like for example crosshair for FPS game (not actually going to do that, just took this as an example). Or how can I set color for some pixels on screen, or something similar. What would be the best way to approach this problem?

Comment: Please see [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). "*Show me how to solve this coding problem*" [is off-topic for Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236). You have to [make an honest attempt at the solution](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592), and then ask a specific question about your implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [OpenCV](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d6/d00/tutorial_py_root.html), that is one of the most useful Computer Vision libraries for Python. You can do whatever you want with images, screencaptures, videos, etc.

But I believe that some prior experience with [NumPy](https://numpy.org/) library is needed, since OpenCV is heavily dependent on it.